# loadShape() causing "ArrayIndexOutOfBounds: 32" in Processing when loading .SVG files

Tags: svg, vector, processing, adobe-illustrator

I'm trying to load a SVG file that I created in Illustrator into my Processing program, but the line 8 causes error "ArrayIndexOutOfOrderException: 32."

```
PShape flwr;

void setup() {
  size(500, 500);
  smooth();
  flwr = loadShape("flower.svg");
}

void draw() {
  background(241, 241, 241);
  shape(flwr, 50, 50);
}
```

I have tried placing "flower.svg" in both the main directory for my program and in the "data" folder in my program's directory.

I feel this might be a problem with the SVG file itself. I exported the file from Illustrator using the following options (as instructed by my instructor):
[Illustrator SVG options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yb2i9.png)

Apologies if this is solely an Illustrator/export problem and I shouldn't be posting it here.

Thanks.

Comment: step 1: _always_ export SVG from illustrator using "export for web" so it saves a real SVG file, instead of an Illustrator-specific SVG file with the full creation/edit history embedded in it. And, once you've done that, it is _strongly_ recommended to run your file through [svgo](https://github.com/svg/svgo) or some other SVG optimizer because holy crap do applications love to overload SVG files with application-specific or even completely inert additional markup that just makes it harder to load the file in things that expect normal SVG files.